# set maximum 3 digit decimal value in in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to store the data in maximum **three digit after decimal point in data base** using **hibernate** 
My Value Storing in db having `column property double 124323.76754287`
while I want to store `124323.76`
If possible Please help me.

Comment: how about `moolah decimal(10,3)` or something

Comment: is this hibernate property?

Comment: The documentation for DECIMAL will explain Precision & Scale - this is what you need to read.

Comment: moolah was the table column name. decimal is the datatype. Hibernate should play pretty with it.

Comment: May I get any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with a table design and test overflow possibilities.

```
create table numTests
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    d2 decimal(10,2) not null,
    d3 decimal(10,3) not null,
    myF float not null,
    myD double not null
);
insert numTests(d2,d3,myF,myD) values
(122.226,122.226,122.2223333,333.44444444); -- decimal place truncate on d2

insert numTests(d2,d3,myF,myD) values
(122.12,122.226,122.2223333,333.44444444); -- no truncate
```

MySQL Manual Pages entitled [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) and [Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)

It would appear that you want to shoot for `DECIMAL`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will use it

Comment: No problem. Remember that floating points (float, double) are generally not your friends unless you are a scientist.